# Mutt, SMTP and automated email sending with new Gmail regulations

Tags: smtp, email-server

I have been using MUTT (SMTP protocols) to automatically send email from a Gmail account. Since May 30th 2022, it seems that Google does not support SMTP protocols for whatever security reasons, and automated sending no longer works.

How to use this Gmail account to keep on sending automated messages with Linux (ubuntu is fact used)? In fact, I would like to know what Linux functionalities could carry out this task, and/or how to reconfigure Mutt to do the job.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Error messages produced by Google server typically include the URL of relevant documentation..

Answer (score 1):

Since the beginning of June I have been unable to use mutt, yesterday I saw a couple of messages from you and I am writing here what worked for me:

1. activate the verification in two steps in the google account
2. create an application password
3. below my `.muttrc`:

```
set ssl_starttls=yes
set ssl_force_tls=yes

set imap_user = 'user@gmail.com'
set imap_pass = 'password'

set from='user@gmail.com'
set realname='user'

set folder = imaps://imap.gmail.com/
set spoolfile = imaps://imap.gmail.com/INBOX
set postponed="imaps://imap.gmail.com/[Gmail]/Drafts"

set header_cache = "~/.mutt/cache/headers"
set message_cachedir = "~/.mutt/cache/bodies"
set certificate_file = "~/.mutt/certificates"

set smtp_url = 'smtps://user@gmail.com:password@smtp.gmail.com:465/'

set move = no
set imap_keepalive = 900
```

Comment: Thanks for the intervention. Before I try, I would like to know which password is to be used where, and whether some delimiters like ' ' are required here and there. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

1. 2step verification must on with your cell number or others
2. create app password
3. put your app password into .muttrc
4. Password shows only once, if you doesn't write yet and forget. Simply just create new one